# Scheduler and Process Context Switch vs Thread Context Switch

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

Trying to understand the scheduler in relation to threads vs processes. One of the benefit of a multithreaded process is a shared address space and a possibility the CPU cache will have the data needed for next execution step. So does a scheduler try to context switch between threads of a single process before context switch to another process?

Comment: Sounds like a plan, other things being equal:)

Comment: It depends on the scheduler. There is no one scheduler policy to rule them all. If you are writing your own you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Depends on the OS. Depends on the version and configuration of the OS. Depends on the language and language runtime environment, or thread library. Depends on if it's pre-emptive. So the answer is maybe.